# Elasticsearch - Get aggregation key sort as number

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I made query result that aggregate some data, and its aggregation key is number. I tried to sort result of aggregation by key. elasticsearch treated key as string.

Since the number of current result bucket is pretty large, it's unable to modify on client side. Any idea of this?

Here is my query.

```
"aggregations" : {
                "startcount" : {
                    "terms" : {
                        "script" : "round(doc['startat'].value/1000)",
                        "size" : 1000,
                        "order" : { "_term" : "asc" }
                    }
                }
             }
```

and current result bucket.

```
    "buckets": [
       {
          "key": "0",
          "doc_count": 68
       },
       {
          "key": "1",
          "doc_count": 21
       },
       {
          "key": "10",
          "doc_count": 6
       },
       {
          "key": "11",
          "doc_count": 16
       },
```

It's my expect result.

```
"buckets": [
   {
      "key": "0",
      "doc_count": 68
   },
   {
      "key": "1",
      "doc_count": 21
   },
   {
      "key": "2", // not '10'
      "doc_count": 6
   },
   {
      "key": "3", // not '11'
      "doc_count": 16
   },
```

Comment: In your mapping, what type does the `startat` field have?

Comment: Type is 'date' and format is 'strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis'.

Comment: I better to use date_histogram. Thanks to give me another viewpoint.

Comment: Maybe you should explain your use case in a bit more details and probably add a sample document to illustrate it.

Comment: I need a count by time period. date_histogram is pretty fit in my case. Last thing I need to find out is its date_histogram key should be number, not like "yyyy-MM-dd HH".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using the [value_script](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_value_script_8) approach should fix the alphabetical sort issue:

Example:

```
 {
   "size": 0,
   "aggregations": {
      "startcount": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "startat",
            "script": "round(_value/1000)",
            "size": 1000,
            "order": {
               "_term": "asc"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: @keety Is there any way to receive `doc_count` value in the script?

Comment: Something like this: `"script": "round(_value/1000) * doc_count",`

Comment: #! Deprecation: Deprecated aggregation order key [_term] used, replaced by [_key].

Answer (score 2):

This is a multiple group by scenario where data are being sorted by the key descending order.

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "categories": {
            "filter": {
                "exists": {
                    "field": "organization_industries"
                }
            },
            "aggs": {
                "names": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "organization_revenue_in_thousands_int.keyword",
                        "size": 200,
                        "order": {
                            "_key": "desc"
                        }
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                        "industry_stats": {
                            "terms": {
                                "field": "organization_industries.keyword"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
"aggregations": {
    "categories": {
        "doc_count": 195161605,
        "names": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 19226983,
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": "99900",
                    "doc_count": 1742,
                    "industry_stats": {
                        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                        "buckets": [
                            {
                                "key": "internet",
                                "doc_count": 1605
                            },
                            {
                                "key": "investment management",
                                "doc_count": 81
                            },
                            {
                                "key": "biotechnology",
                                "doc_count": 54
                            },
                            {
                                "key": "computer & network security",
                                "doc_count": 2
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },                
                {
                    "key": "998000",
                    "doc_count": 71,
                    "industry_stats": {
                        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                        "buckets": [
                            {
                                "key": "finance",
                                "doc_count": 48
                            },
                            {
                                "key": "information technology & services",
                                "doc_count": 23
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
                
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```